# Appium - RemoteWebDriver vs AppiumDriver initiation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

What is the difference between initiating appium driver by using this

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

and

```
driver = new AppiumDriver(url, desiredCapabilities);
```

in terms of pre-requisites for initiating and the automation that they can handle or any other difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the answer in [this](http://discuss.appium.io/t/what-is-the-use-or-difference-between-androiddriver-iosdriver-appiumdriver-and-remote-webdriver/8750/2) post.

Also , I came across a post , have a look at [this](http://www.aosabook.org/en/selenium.html) . Its an excellent post about the selenium/webdriver architecture and its history which may clear a lot of doubts for some one looking for knowledge in this area. Specially in understanding how webdriver works internally end to end, from  language binding command to return of the element.

**EDIT: copy pasting from link above**

RemoteWebDriver: This driver class comes directly from the upstream Selenium project. This is a pretty generic driver where initializing the driver means making network requests to a Selenium hub to start a driver session. Since Appium operates on the client-server model, Appium uses this to initialize a driver session. However, directly using the RemoteWebDriver is not recommended since there are other drivers available that offer additional features or convenience functions.

AppiumDriver: This driver class inherits from the RemoteWebDriver class, but it adds in additional functions that are useful in the context of a mobile automation test through the Appium server.

AndroidDriver: This driver class inherits from AppiumDriver, but it adds in additional functions that are useful in the context of a mobile automation test on Android devices through Appium. Only use this driver class if you want to start a test on an Android device or Android emulator.

IOSDriver: This driver class inherits from AppiumDriver, but it adds in additional functions that are useful in the context of a mobile automation test on iOS devices through Appium. Only use this driver class if you want to start a test on an iOS device or iOS emulator.

As you can see, the drivers and their names tie in closely with what they do. When it comes to initializing a driver, only use the Android or IOS drivers.