# How to get Appium Android Driver?

Tags: android, selenium, android-studio, kotlin, appium

I'm confused about how to use Appium with Android studio.  Specifically how to use the Android Driver.

I have read many docs and instructions on how it is *supposed* to be done.  All of which seem to change drastically between releases.

Many recent sites (e.g. [tutorial example](https://www.headspin.io/blog/appium/writing-an-appium-test-in-kotlin/)) talk about using the Android Driver that comes with the Appium rather than the WebDriver.  But that means you have to import:

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
```

But despite having included all that I can find in sites and here the standard includes don't seem to give access to the driver's library.

Meaning that I am unable to import anything from the io.* path.

[Documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.appium/java-client/3.1.0/io/appium/java_client/package-tree.html)

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59'
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:3.141.59'
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:3.141.59'
```

What I think that I need to do is the following:

```
var driver: WebDriver = AndroidDriver(URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities)
```

edit:

But I can't import `import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver` and the driver does not seem to be a part of the Selenium libs.

/edit

Any ideas how I get to use the Android Driver/what I'm doing wrong?

[Delta between different drivers in Appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735017/appium-remotewebdriver-vs-appiumdriver-initiation)

Thanks so much!

Comment: can you import `io.appium.java_client` as an external library? so you will be able to use it

Comment: Good question!
I should have mentioned that I am unable to import anything io.* related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the selenium dependencies from the project and only use io.appium/java-client dependency.

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client
compile group: 'io.appium', name: 'java-client', version: '7.3.0'
```

Refer : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/7.3.0 . java-client already has selenium dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [documentation](https://github.com/appium/java-client) on how to add `Appium` to Android project:

1. Using **Gradle** Add the JitPack repository to your build file. Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

   ```
   allprojects {
       repositories {
           ...
           maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add the dependency to app's **build.gradle** file:

   ```
   dependencies {
       implementation 'com.github.appium:java-client:7.3.0'
   }
   ```
3. Now you are able to import and create drivers:

   ```
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
   import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver

   //...

   var driver: WebDriver = AndroidDriver(URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities)
   ```